# cocos2d/cocos2d-x: Adding tile to the layer

Tags: cocos2d-x

Please tell me how to Tilemap on the layer you want to add a tile?
Rummaged through all the documentation and did not find. How to remove a tile layer, I realized:

```
[_meta removeTileAt:tileCoord];
```

How to add a tile layer? Prompt please.
Generally I need to become an obstacle selected tile.

Comment: please state complete problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe there is a Class called `CCTMXTiledMap` in cocos2d-x. You can add map like this in cocos2d-x in `CCLayer`:

```
map = CCTMXTiledMap::create("stonemap.tmx");
this->addChild(map,0,tagMap);
```

Comment: Generally I need to become an obstacle selected tile.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...by

```
map = CCTMXTiledMap::create("stonemap.tmx");
CCTMXLayer x=map->layerNamed("layer_name") 
//layer_name is name you give to your layer Ex...backGround_Layer,Obstacle_Layer
```

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/hub/23#How-to-getadddeletemodify-a-tile) where m_gid is your resources ID :)

```
layer->setTileGID(m_gid, tileCoord);
```